# div tag not getting appended to another div tag using append method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Could anyone please tell me why the `div` with `button` id is not getting appended to the div with `clickable` class in the code below.

```
var $el = $("<div/>", {class: "clickable",style: "margin:100px 10px 20px 20px ",}).append($("<div />", { id: "button"})).on('click', handleClick);
```

I didn't see anything in the console log when I did the following :

```
console.log("Element el test");
  console.log($el);
```

I want to append the `div` with `id = button` to the `div` with `clickable` class so that I could display a button below each table/grid using this   `$("#button").jqxButton({ value: 'Export Grid '});`
  But for some reason, it's not showing up in the console log statements as mentioned above.

Secondly, I would be attaching an event to the button once it starts showing up below the grid/table. Basically, I will be doing something like this :

```
 $("#button" ).on('click', function () {
       $(".clickable").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'pdf', 'jqxGrid');
  });
```

So, I am not sure if the following approach of appending is good or not because there's already a onclick event attached. So, I am imagining that even if the following approach starts working, clicking the `div` with 
`button` id will do the same thing that is achieved when the `div` containing `clickable` class is clicked?

```
 var $el = $("<div/>", {class: "clickable",style: "margin:100px 10px 20px 20px ",}).append($("<div />", { id: "button"})).on('click', handleClick);
```

```js
var source = {
  localdata: [
    ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Maria Anders", "Sales Representative", "Obere Str. 57", "Berlin", "Germany"],
    ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Ana Trujillo", "Owner", "Avda. de la Constitucin 2222", "Mxico D.F.", "Mexico"],
    ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Antonio Moreno", "Owner", "Mataderos 2312", "Mxico D.F.", "Mexico"],
    ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Thomas Hardy", "Sales Representative", "120 Hanover Sq.", "London", "UK"],
    ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Christina Berglund", "Order Administrator", "Berguvsvgen 8", "Lule", "Sweden"],
    ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Hanna Moos", "Sales Representative", "Forsterstr. 57", "Mannheim", "Germany"],
    ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Roland Mendel", "Sales Manager", "Kirchgasse 6", "Graz", "Austria"]
  ],
  datafields: [{
      name: 'link',
      type: 'string',
      map: '0'
    },
    {
      name: 'ContactName',
      type: 'string',
      map: '1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Title',
      type: 'string',
      map: '2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Address',
      type: 'string',
      map: '3'
    },
    {
      name: 'City',
      type: 'string',
      map: '4'
    },
    {
      name: 'Country',
      type: 'string',
      map: '5'
    }
  ],
  datatype: "array"
};
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);


$(".clickable").jqxGrid({
  width: 800,
  height: 270,
  source: dataAdapter,
  columnsresize: true,
  sortable: true,
  columns: [{
      text: 'Link',
      datafield: 'link',
      width: 200
    },
    {
      text: 'Contact Name',
      datafield: 'ContactName',
      width: 150
    },
    {
      text: 'Contact Title',
      datafield: 'Title',
      width: 100
    },
    {
      text: 'Address',
      datafield: 'Address',
      width: 100
    },
    {
      text: 'City',
      datafield: 'City',
      width: 100
    },
    {
      text: 'Country',
      datafield: 'Country'
    }
  ]
});

$(".clickable").on("rowselect", handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
  var $el = $("<div/>", {
    class: "clickable",
    style: "margin:100px 10px 20px 20px ",
  }).append($("<div />", {
    id: "button"
  })).on('click', handleClick);

  console.log("Element el test");
  console.log($el);

  /*var buttonDiv = $("<div />", {
    id: "button"
  });
  console.log("Testing button Div");
  console.log(buttonDiv);

  $("#button").jqxButton({
    value: 'Export Grid '
  });*/

  $el.jqxGrid({
    height: 270,
    source: dataAdapter,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Link',
        datafield: 'link',
        width: 200
      },
      {
        text: 'Contact Name',
        datafield: 'ContactName',
        width: 150
      },
      {
        text: 'Contact Title',
        datafield: 'Title',
        width: 100
      },
      {
        text: 'Address',
        datafield: 'Address',
        width: 100
      },
      {
        text: 'City',
        datafield: 'City',
        width: 100
      },
      {
        text: 'Country',
        datafield: 'Country'
      }
    ]
  });

  var $this = $(this),
    $parent = $(this).parent();

  if (e.type == 'rowselect') {
    $('.clickable').slice(1).remove();
  }
  $parent.append($el);
}
```

```css
.test {
  margin: 100px 10px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="clickable" style="margin:100px 10px 20px 20px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `$el` is getting assigned to the return value of your last `.on` call.

You probably want to do something more like this

```
var $el = $("<div/>", {class: "clickable",style: "margin:100px 10px 20px 20px ",});
var $nested = $("<div />", { id: "button"});

$el.append($nested);
$nested.on('click', handleClick);
```

Comment: Thanks but I am still not seeing it getting appended in the console log. Also, after adding your code, my code stopped working, I mean, when I clicked on the first grid, I could see second grid below. But nothing happens if I click on second grid.